# In PHP, does elseif need a final else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is it ok to leave out the final else statement in an elseif block in PHP. Is this code OK

```
if ( condition ):
   // code
elseif ( othercondition ):
   // more code
endif;
```

or should it have else at the end ?

```
if ( condition ):
   // code
elseif ( othercondition ):
   // more code
else
   // more code
endif;
```

I'm sure it must be but I cant get it confirmed anywhere. Edit - I've tried it and it works but I just want to be sure.

Comment: You have code there — try it.

Comment: @arxanas I dont think trying it is a guaranteed way to know that it's ok, do you?

Comment: You can totally dismiss the else condition, but conceptually, it's always better to have one.

Comment: Short answer: No! - Long answer: You have to check, by your self, if it is necesery to have a final `else` as fallback or not.

Comment: both @JérômeBoé and Raisch are incorrect. Others are correct.

Comment: @Raisch so you're saying "No" as in there's a problem with it ... by the way note my edit

Comment: @Asaph - Question was: _In PHP, does elseif need a final else statement?_ - My answer is: _No._ - So tell me where i am wrong there.

Comment: @Raisch I stand corrected, you are right - I actually asked it both ways, sorry

Comment: @Raisch: The OP asked it both ways. Once in the title and then again in the first sentence of the question. I interpreted your "No" to be the answer to "Is it ok to leave out the final else statement in an elseif block in PHP?". Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Asaph - Thats why i put the long answer at the end. :)

Comment: noteworthy isn't it ? .... it's easy to forget and phrase it one way in the title and the other in the body.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you don't need a final `else`-block, don't write one. it's just senseless to have a block of code (possibly containing just a `this is useless`-comment) that isn't needed.

Answer (score 6):

While @oezi's answer is 100% correct, I would also add that with respect to *best practice*, the `else` condition *should* be used in all cases.  This does not mean you have to use an `else` block literally, though, since you can accomplish the same thing logically by putting your "else code" before the `if`.  For example:

```
$foo = 'baz';

if (...) {
    $foo = 'foo';
} else if (...) {
    $foo = 'bar';
}
```

...is functionally equivalent to:

```
if (...) {
    $foo = 'foo';
} else if (...) {
    $foo = 'bar';
} else {
    $foo = 'baz';
}
```

I would argue that the use of `else` is more clear when reading the code, but either way is okay.  Just remember that leaving out the third case altogether is a common cause of bugs (and in some cases, even security holes).

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of why I was asking the question, I hadn't seen it done that often so I figured there is a reason.